# How to get specialized in UI/UX testing?

Tags: gui

I have been asked to work with our UI/UX director recently to test our UI stuffs. I am bit nervous as its completely new area. So far, i have been in functional testing and did test for UI alignment issues. I Just wanted to know how to get started with UI/UX testing ? ANy materials, Blog , links would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of application? Web or client application?

Comment: Primarily Web, we also have Mobile App as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have read two great books written by [Steve Krug](http://www.sensible.com), which I think are a must read for anyone doing usability testing.

- [Don't Make Me Think](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/10-usability-lessons-from-steve-krugs-dont-make-me-think/)
- [Rocket Surgery Made Easy](http://abetteruserexperience.com/2011/10/steve-krug-book-review/)

Both are easy to read and you should be able to read both in a day (or two).

Maybe also ask the question on https://ux.stackexchange.com/, guess that community might have better getting started pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best single book to read for your situation is [The Design of Everyday Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465050654) by Donald Norman. He's the other half Norman / Nielsen group linked in Peter's answer and a pioneer of the usability field.

He talks about a lot of important concepts like [affordances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance), [mappings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_mapping_(interface_design)), [forcing functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-shaping_constraint), and so many many others.

The concepts in this book are valuable because they are an effective lens through which to evaluate your UI and a useful vocabulary to communicate what you observe.

A made up example:

> the password constraints aren't revealed when registering, requiring users to repeatedly guess until they succeed or quit.

Uses the shared concepts of constraint and feedback to describe friction in the user experience.

However:

> it's too difficult to find an acceptable password on the registration form.

*Could* be a UX issue, or possibly a bug with form validation, or possibly a bug with posting the form, etc.

There isn't a single website mentioned in this book if I recall, but the underlying concepts are applicable to any user experience, which I find pretty amazing.

Answer (score 0):

**UI**

General

- Ask for a style guide, if you do not have one.
- The style guide should have a list with the allowed colors. Exactly values like hex code or something similar.

Web

- Test in different browsers.
- Ask what browser they want to support. Look about market share and keep up-to-date.
- Create a priority list of browsers in three categories: A(Important), B, C.

Mobile App

- Test on real different devices and do not use emulators.
- The most things will be displayed correctly on iPhone or new Android devices. But also take a look to the older one.
- Test x devices in parallel. One of them should be an device without known problems as a reference. Navigate between the difference screens and compare the device screens to discover device / OS specific problems.
- Create a priority list of devices / OS in three categories: A(Important), B, C.
- Try to get new devices fast as you can.

Testing mobile apps is very hard. You has so many combinations: devices * operating systems * app versions.

**UX**

- Test on the users point of view.
- Test that forms, navigation elements ect. has the same composition/colors on the different pages/screens. For example: The Cancel button is always gray and the Submit button always green.

---

I am sure that many additional points exists. But these come up into my mind at first.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical source of knowledge about UI testing for last 20 years is http://useit.com. Jacob Nielsen is "guru of website usability" for those 20 years. Subscribe to his emails, and read his website.